# RaisePropertyChanged not updating properties when function called from another viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

This class is used to bind search result in listbox and onselected list it will show result in overview panel, both are two different view model.

```
public class SearchClients : Client
```

{
    public Client Client;

```
private void SelectedClient(int PartyId)
{
    List<Client> c = this.fileService.FindClients(PartyId, "", "").ToList();
    if (c.Count > 0)
    {
        Client = c[0];
    }
    OverviewPageViewModel viewModel = this.injector.Resolve<OverviewPageViewModel>("OverviewPage");
    viewModel.SelectedClient(Client);
}
```

}

Search Panel View Model

```
 public class SearchBar : BaseContentViewModel
{ 
       private void FindClients()
    {
        List<Client> C = fileService.FindClients(0, SrchFirstName, SrchLastName).ToList();

}

    public ICommand FindClient
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(FindClients);
        }
    }
}
```

Result Panel View Model

```
   public class OverviewPageViewModel: BaseContentViewModel  
{
    public void SelectedClient(Client Client)
    { 
        Title = Client.TitleID; 
        FirstName = Client.FirstName;
        LastName = Client.LastName;

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to frame your question correctly instead of directly pasting the code. Read link[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: I don't follow what the problem is. If a base viewmodel is in a different dll then I occasionally find I have to explicitly stick the inpc interface on the leaf class before things notice it really does implement inpc. Maybe that has nothing to do with your problem though. I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel was assigned base class IContentViewModel in tab navigation, it should be initiated with OverviewPageViewModel which have all properties. Solved!!

Wrong:

```
IContentViewModel viewModel = injector.Resolve<IContentViewModel>(TabPage);
```

Correct:

```
IContentViewModel viewModel = injector.Resolve<IContentViewModel>(TabPage);
        if (TabPage == "OverviewPage")
        {
            injector.Resolve<ViewModels.Windows.MainWindowViewModel>().CurrentPageViewModel = injector.Resolve<OverviewPageViewModel>(TabPage);
        }
        else
        {
            //viewModel.ClearData();
            injector.Resolve<ViewModels.Windows.MainWindowViewModel>().CurrentPageViewModel = viewModel;
        }
```